# How to merge arrays of objects into a JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I fail miserably at combining all the required transformations. For those more at ease with data manipulation, a little help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Visual representation of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
[
    [
        {
            name : 'a',
            value : 'b'
        },
        {
            name : 'c',
            value : 'd'
        },
        ...
    ],
    [
        {
            name : 'e',
            value : 'f'
        },
        {
            name : 'g',
            value : 'h'
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
]

// to

[
    {
        a : 'b',
        c : 'd'
    },
    {
        e : 'f',
        g : 'h'
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Two things. Pretty sure it's a copy and paste error, but you have `b` and `d` as values for both sets of keys. You seem to have lost `f` and `h`. Is this a typo or is it the desired behavior? The second note is that what you're showing is not valid JSON. JSON requires that keys and values be quoted in double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`.

Comment: Show us *how* you failed, so that we can help you specifically with *your* code. Otherwise it would be trivial: `return arr.map(function(els){return els.reduce(function(m,el){m[el.name]=el.value;return m;},{});})` - hardly helpful for you.

Comment: I edited my question regarding the copy paste error. I don't have any code left of my attempts, it was just a big mess really. I'm usually pretty ok at using these data manipulation functions with simple use cases but this one I got confused. How could I train myself to the level where such a problem is "trivial" as you pointed out? Thanks for the solution anyway.

Comment: Dunno, 24/7 training by answering StackOverflow questions? :-) A clear mental model of what arrays/objects are and how they are structured also helps at identifying the necessary traversing actions. Learning functional programming as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/b8YyL/

here's the code:

```
var original = [
    [
        {
            name : 'a',
            value : 'b'
        },
        {
            name : 'c',
            value : 'd'
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            name : 'e',
            value : 'f'
        },
        {
            name : 'g',
            value : 'h'
        },
    ],
]


function translateNameValueObjects(items) {
    var map = {},
    item,
    i;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item = items[i];
        map[item.name] = item.value;
    }
    return map;
}

var mapped = original.map(translateNameValueObjects);
alert(JSON.stringify(mapped));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. hop this help you!

```
var jsonArray = [
    [
        {
            name : 'a',
            value : 'b'
        },
        {
            name : 'c',
            value : 'd'
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            name : 'e',
            value : 'f'
        },
        {
            name : 'g',
            value : 'h'
        },
    ]
];

var modifiedJsonArray = [];        
if(jsonArray.length){
    for(var i=0; i<jsonArray.length; i++){
        if(jsonArray[i].length){
            for(var j=0; j<jsonArray[i].length; j++){
                modifiedJsonArray.push("{"+jsonArray[i][j].name+":"+jsonArray[i][j].value+"}")
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(modifiedJsonArray);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/f7euL/

Comment: Those `if`-tests are absolutely superfluous.

Comment: @Bergi- The above answer is useful. than mark a answer is useful.

Comment: *I* think long-winded code is *not* useful. Please let me vote with my own opion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function:

```
var data = [
 [
    {
        name : 'a',
        value : 'b'
    },
    {
        name : 'c',
        value : 'd'
    },
 ],
 [
    {
        name : 'e',
        value : 'f'
    },
    {
        name : 'g',
        value : 'h'
    }
 ]
];

data = data.reduce(function(a, b, i){
    a[i] = b.reduce(function(c, d){
        c[d.name] = d.value;
        return c;
    }, {});
    return a;
}, []);
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7whFy/1/